# C - a simple expression for counting combinations in a range of numbers?

Tags: c, math

Well really a vague statement (to me)

What is the basic expression to calculate:

- "The number of combinations of n things taken k at a time as an integer"

*Edit:* 
A little more clarification: 
 "For example, the combinations of four items a,b,c,d taken three at a time  are abc, abd, acd, and bcd. In other words, there are a total of four different combinations of four things "taken three at a time"."

I'm taking a non introductory C class while attempt to complete my math requirements to transfer for a CS degree. I am getting very high scores on all of my work thus far, but when higher level math comes up I really get stuck. But I digress..

The range of numbers would be 1-10 for *n*
and *k*'s range would be 1-4.

Below is the only reference I have received and it is way over my head.

http://www.themathpage.com/aPreCalc/permutations-combinations-2.htm

Comment: If that page, which is a clear and precise answer to your question, is over your head, then I'm not sure what we can do to help you. It just sounds like you need to learn a lot more math than you have. We can't teach you math here.

Comment: Take a look at [Wikipedia.org: Binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula)

Comment: You can also check out [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). You can also ask math questions at our sister site [Math.SE].

Comment: do it on paper in long hand, keep messing with it until it becomes clear and the solution hits you or you decide CS may be the wrong path (whichever comes first)

Comment: If you want to make progress, you need to look at ***what exactly*** on that page is *way over your head* and start addressing that problem. Obviously, it's the page you need help with **first**, then you can procede to the C code. ***So***: Where on the page are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic expression is n!/(k!(n-k)!). An efficient way to calculate this is to use a 2D DP table of pascal's triangle.

Comment: could this be written as `n(factorial)/(k(factorial(n-k)factorial)

Comment: The exclamation mark indicates the factorial operation. e.g. n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1.

Answer (score 1):

The key expression on the page is:

- <sup>n</sup>C<sub>k</sub> =  n! ÷ ((n − k)! k!)

This is the simple expression for the 'number of combinations of *n* things taken *k* at a time'.  The term *<sup>n</sup>C<sub>k</sub>* is the way mathematicians write 'the number of combinations of *n* things taken *k* at a time'.  The expression on the right is a succinct, accurate and simple method of calculating the correct value.   It presupposes that you know that *n!* is factorial *n*, and that 'factorial *n*' means each number between 1 and *n* multiplied together.

Be aware that *n!* gets very big very quickly, so the naïve algorithms will work up to about *n = 12* but go much beyond that and you have to be very careful indeed.

- 0! = 1
- 1! = 1
- 2! = 2
- 3! = 6
- 4! = 24
- 5! = 120
- 6! = 720
- 7! = 5040
- 8! = 40320
- 9! = 362880
- 10! = 3628800
- 11! = 39916800
- 12! = 479001600
- 13! = 6227020800

Note that 13! is too big to fit into a 32-bit unsigned integer, and 21! is too big to fit into a 64-bit unsigned integer, and 35! is too big to fit into a 128-bit unsigned integer (if you can find a computer with such a type).

If you still can't cope, then you are going to face problems in your transfer; this is not very complicated mathematics.

Comment: could this be written as n(factorial) + ((n-k)factorial k factorial)

Comment: this is what I need to write "each number between 1 and n multiplied together"

Comment: More likely you'd write it as `factorial(n) / (factorial(n-k) * factorial(k))` in C.

Comment: More likely you'd write it as `factorial(n) / (factorial(n-k) * factorial(k))` in C.  You could write the function `unsigned factorial(unsigned n) { ... }` which does the calculation, or simply create an array with the values and return the correct element of the array (since the range of valid values is so small).